# deja-dup triggers disk I/O failures on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: kernel, 17.04, ecryptfs, deja-dup, smart

I have a newly installed 17.04 (from scratch) on a fully encrypted disk, with an encrypted home dir.

If I run deja-dup to make a backup, it is guaranteed that the system will crash. If I tail /var/log/syslog, it will ssays something about lowering the ata1 speeds down to 3.0GB. Unfortunately I don't have the exact message because it puts the system in such a state that nothing gets written to disk.

The only option is to force poweroff and restart the system, at which point /var/log/syslog doesn't contain the ata1 speed messages anymore.

I checked the SSD's status with SMART, everything is OK there.

How can I tell if this is a deja-dup issue or something else? And how can I resolve this issue?

--edit: I managed to take some pictures (since it won't log anything to disk)

It starts with `Failed command: FLUSH CACHE EXT`, `COMRESET failed (errno=16)`, then the system switches to read only, and the only way out is force poweroff.

[image: First, this happens]

[image: Then, that]

--edit: This is the SMART data for the SSD in question:

```
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-4.10.0-20-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Intel 520 Series SSDs
Device Model:     INTEL SSDSC2BW180A3L
Serial Number:    *****
LU WWN Device Id: *****
Firmware Version: LE1i
User Capacity:    180,045,766,656 bytes [180 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2 (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sun May 14 09:27:50 2017 EDT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7f) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Abort Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  48) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x0021) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours_and_Msec 0x0032   080   080   000    Old_age   Always       -       18301h+22m+34.340s
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       2294
170 Available_Reservd_Space 0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
171 Program_Fail_Count      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
172 Erase_Fail_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
174 Unexpect_Power_Loss_Ct  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       816
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       261
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0033   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
187 Uncorrectable_Error_Cnt 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       816
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
225 Host_Writes_32MiB       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       311454
226 Workld_Media_Wear_Indic 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       65535
227 Workld_Host_Reads_Perc  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       52
228 Workload_Minutes        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       65535
232 Available_Reservd_Space 0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
233 Media_Wearout_Indicator 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
241 Host_Writes_32MiB       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       311454
242 Host_Reads_32MiB        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       348910
249 NAND_Writes_1GiB        0x0013   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       12890

SMART Error Log not supported

SMART Self-test Log not supported

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 0
Note: revision number not 1 implies that no selective self-test has ever been run
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Comment: "deja-dup triggers disk I/O failures" Sorry but I doubt that. I'd rather think deja-dup runs into I/O failures when making a backup. Or: Deja-dup is not the *source* for these i/o failures it is a *result* of your hard disk going bad.

Comment: I'd start with a filesystem check (`sudo touch /forcechk` and reboot).

Comment: filesystem check returns no errors. I have used this drive for months on 16.10 and it was fine. Those errors only appear in 17.04; when 17.04 came out, I tried it and ran into these issues. Went back to 16.10 without errors until today. So there is something about the combination 17.04 + deja-dup + my system that doesn't occur on 16.10.